# Why does this part of my code always return the value 0?

Tags: c

So, I tried to make a program of eratosthenes sieve  in c, but every value gets turned to 0,
specifically this is the part that causes trouble but I can't figure out what goes wrong

```
for (i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
    if (checkprime(nums[i], i)) {
        for (count = 2; i * count <= max; ++count) {
            nums[(i-1) * count] = 0;
        }
    }
    else nums[i] = 0;
}
```

this is the "checkprime" function

```
int checkprime(int num,int count) {
    for (count = count; count <= num / 2; ++count) {
        if (num % count == 0) {
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop in `checkprime()` returns in the first iteration, no matter what. I don't understand the purpose of passing `count` though. Anyway, one of the points of making a sieve, is that you collect the next prime *from the sieve*. It's the next value that has not been "crossed off", and there is no need for any trial division primality test.

Comment: how would I go about making that? Not looking for code snippets necessarily, just some pointers

Comment: For a small range, I use an array of `char`, for a larger range an array of bits, all initialised to `0`. The first prime is known to be `2` so you start at index `2*2` and set the value of that and every 2nd element to `1`. Then the next value still `0` is at index `3`. That's the next prime, so you start at index `3*3` and set the value of that and every third element to `1`. Then the next value still `0` is at index `5`. That's the next prime, so you start at index `5*5` and set the value of that and every fifth element to `1`. If you need a *list* of primes, put each into another array.

Comment: ... so you work your way through the sieve, and whenever you find a `0`: that's a prime, you put it in the array of primes, and "cross off" all its multiples, beginning with its square. Why the square? Consider finding the prime `5`, you don't need to cross off `5 * 2` and `5 * 3` because you already crossed off `2 * 5` and `3 * 5` earlier. In practice, I don't consider even numbers at all, but treat them as a special case.

Comment: Thank you, would you happen to have an idea as to why my code isn't working?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I'm trying to check for every prime number in my array and turn the values for every number = prime * count into 0, so in the end I'm left with an array in which only prime numbers have the value 1 (I can post the code if you want, some ~65 lines of code)(I should also clarify that at the start every element of the array is equal to 1)

Comment: I'll post a little example in about an hour's time.

Comment: thank you, i'll try to cross-reference it with mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code to show how a sieve is made, and primes extracted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIMIT 100

int main(void) {

    char *sieve = calloc(LIMIT, sizeof *sieve);
    if(sieve == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
        
    for(int n = 2; n < LIMIT; n++) {
        if(sieve[n] == 0) {             // found a prime
            printf("%d ", n);
            for(int i = n * n; i < LIMIT; i += n) {
                sieve[i] = 1;           // mark off multiples
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    free(sieve);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```